# Big emojis in built-in messages app on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos, applications, messages, emoji

Is there any way to show big emojis when sending 3 or fewer emojis in built-in messages app on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, like on iOS 12 and macOS Sierra and higher ?

Comment: I think that came with maybe Sierra, so no, not possible before that. [Can't add as an answer because I cannot find a citation]

Comment: Okay, but can't it be like a "mac jailbreak" to change built-in application content?

Comment: No. You can update to Sierra, or higher, assuming your Mac can handle it.

Comment: I don't update to Sierra just because my Mac can't handle it... Unfortunately.